# electric water heater wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Main panel has one 100 double breaker and two 60 amp double breakers.  There are extra slots for more breakers. Can I install a 30 am double breaker in on of the extra slots to wire up a 30 amp electric water heater with 10 gauge wire?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can.  But your total electrical may now be too much.  It depends on your service capacity.